# Is it recommended on jQuery to change all $("speakup") with $speakup?

Tags: jquery, performance

In the jQuery source code

Is it recommended to do this?  I have a button whose ID is speakup

Then is it more efficient to

```
var $speakup = $("#speakup");
```

and $speakup in the jQuery source instead?  That will make it faster because it no longer needs to search through the DOM?  Is it recommended to do that for all buttons on my jQuery source?

And what are some of the commonly recommended ways to improve my jQuery?  Any well-known tips and tricks you could share?  Thanks Stack Overflow

Comment: See [this](http://begeeben.wordpress.com/2012/08/30/this-this-this-and-that/) .. may be useful

Comment: var something = $('#speakup') will work faster than making jquery object of '#speakup' over and over again in every time You need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Is it recommended to do this?

It is if you reuse the jQuery element. So in a code like this :

```
$('#anElement').on('click', function(){
    $('#anElement').toggle();
});
```

It is recommended performance wise to cache your element :

```
var $el = $('#anElement');
$el.on('click', function(){
    $el.toggle();
});
```

If you do only one thing with the element, then it is not usefull.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#anElement').remove(); //Not useful to cache.
});
```

**Note:** jQuery methods almost always return the jQuery element, so most of the time, you can cache an element while doing something. 2 birds with 1 stone :

```
var $el = $(#anElement).on('click', function(){
    $el.toggle();
});
```

## And what are some of the commonly recommended ways to improve my jQuery? Any well-known tips and tricks you could share?

A common trick is to chain the jQuery method. That also improve performance.

```
$('#anElement')
.attr('title', 'Hey!')
.css('color', 'red')
[0].click();
```

That snippet would take an element, change its title to 'Hey!', change his text color to red and the get the HTMLElement and trigger the native click.

Comment: De rien, gentilhomme!

Answer (score 2):

That totally depends if you want the object to be reused or not.

Using `$('selector')` will internally try to search the element in DOM everytime you use it. Imagine using `$("#speakup")` 5-6 times here, every time the selector is used jquery will find the object in DOM.

**Conclusion:**  If you want the object to be used multiple times, then store the reference in variable and use that variable in future.

However it is not a good practice for elements/DOM getting changed. In this case the reference stored will be of that of old DOM. So you will need to recreate the dom reference when changes occurs in DOM.